# In Angular JS, is there a way to watch for changes to the DOM without using scope.watch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am attempting to create an angularjs bootstrap accordion that scrolls the accordion to the top when opened.

These solutions are close to what I would like to do:

- [AngularJS / ui-bootstrap accordion - scroll to top of active (open) accordion on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152485/)
- https://www.peterbouda.eu/making-an-angular-ui-bootstrap-accordion-scrolling-to-top-when-opening.html

However, they use a timeout or scope watches. I would like to avoid using these unless absolutely necessary.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using `$watch` or `setTimeout`?

Here is a plunk of what i am trying to do, this is using the $watch: https://plnkr.co/edit/XQpUdrdjqaCGom4L9yIJ

```
app.directive( 'scrollTop', scrollTop );

function scrollTop() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
}

function link( scope, element ) {
    scope.collapsing = false;
    var jqElement = $( element) ;
    scope.$watch( function() {
        return jqElement.find( '.panel-collapse' ).hasClass( 'collapsing' );
    }, function( status ) {
        if ( scope.collapsing && !status ) {
            if ( jqElement.hasClass( 'panel-open' ) ) {
                $( 'html,body' ).animate({
                    scrollTop: jqElement.offset().top - 30
                }, 500 );
            }
        }
        scope.collapsing = status;
    } );
}
```

Comment: Probably with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Can you show us your code and watches?

Comment: @Dalorzo I have updated my question with plunkr code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this from the controller.

I added a function that is triggered on `ng-click` to report the `is-open` status of the accordion.

Using the component lifecycle hook `$doCheck` I was able to watch for changes to the state of `vm.isOpen`. `$doCheck` runs on the end of every digest cycle, so I did not need to set a `$scope.watch` or `$timeOut`

The `$doCheck` runs essentially the same code as the directive in the question

```
app.controller('homeController', function($state, $element, sections, $transitions) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.$onInit = function() {
    vm.sections = sections.getSections();
  };

  function updateOpenStatus() {
    vm.collapsing = false;
    vm.isOpen = vm.sections.some(function(item) {
      return item.isOpen;
    });
  }

  vm.$doCheck = function() {
    if (vm.isOpen) {
      var elem = $element.find('.panel-collapse');
      var status = elem.hasClass('collapsing');
      if (vm.collapsing && !status) {
        var parentElem = elem.closest('.panel-open');
        if (elem.parent().hasClass('panel-open')) {
          $('html,body')
            .stop()
            .animate({
              scrollTop: parentElem.offset().top - 52
            }, 'fast');
        }
      }
      vm.collapsing = status;
    }
  };
});
```

I updated the `uib-accordion` to call the function in the controller

```
<uib-accordion>
  <div heading="Section Title" is-open="section.isOpen" ng-repeat="section in vm.sections" scroll-top uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      <div ng-class="{isOpen: section.isOpen}" ng-click="vm.toggleOpen()">
        <h3>{{section.sectionTitle}}</h3>
      </div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div class="clearfix">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Updated Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5EqDfmVOa0hzFfaQqdI0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The directive can be simplified to:<sup>[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/8V34iNaGSfIeB9N0dUur?p=preview)</sup>

```
app.directive( 'scrollTop', function scrollTop($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on("click", function(e) {
          if (scope.status.isOpen) {
            $timeout(function() {
              $( 'html,body' ).animate({
                scrollTop: elem.offset().top - 30
              }, 500 );
            });
          }
        });
    }
})
```

```
<uib-accordion>
  <div heading="Section Title" is-open="status.isOpen"
       ng-repeat="section in vm.sections"
       scroll-top
       uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      <div ng-class="{isOpen: vm.isOpen}">
        <h3>{{section.sectionTitle}}</h3>
        <p>{{section.sectionSubHeader}}</p>
      </div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <b>Index+1={{$index+1}}</b> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

The `$timeout` is necessary because the browser needs to render the DOM with the newly opened and closed elements before it can compute the proper scroll offset.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/8V34iNaGSfIeB9N0dUur?p=preview)

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using the `$timeout` by using the `$doCheck` of the component lifecycle? I use $doCheck in other controllers to update the DOM with asynchronous content. I would also like to avoid using a `$scope` variable, and use a controller scope variable, if possible.